# Error CocAction("extensionStats") does not work

Tags: vim, coc.nvim, neovim

Every time I enter neovim in windows 10 to a .js file I get this error:

```
Error detected while processing function SwitchFlowOrTsLsps[1]..CocAction:
line    2:
E605: Exception not caught: coc.nvim not ready when invoke CocAction "extensionStats"
```

In my configuration file is the function for which the error occurs:

```
function! SwitchFlowOrTsLsps(flowIndex)
  silent let stats = CocAction("extensionStats")
  silent let tsserver = get(filter(copy(stats), function('FindTsServer')), 0)
  if(a:flowIndex == 0)
    if(tsserver.state == 'disabled')
      call CocActionAsync("toggleExtension", "coc-tsserver")
    endif
  else
    if(tsserver.state == 'activated')
      call CocActionAsync("toggleExtension", "coc-tsserver")
    endif
  endif
endfunction
```

Could someone help me? Although to tell me to delete the function, that function along with some more configurations I copied them from github and I don't understand it, I don't understand what it does.

**It could even be a Coc error, that's how I see it but I'm not sure how to fix it, I have coc-json and coc-tsserver installed, if I need any more just say so.**

Thank you all.

Comment: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues

Comment: @romainl Thanks I already uploaded my question there I hope you can answer me soon, since it is annoying every time I enter a file

Answer (score 0):

> coc.nvim not ready when invoke

You need to make sure your coc.nvim has started already before invoke this action.

Comment: How do I verify that? Or how do I start it?